# Powershell script to list all users whose manager account is disabled

Tags: powershell

I have modified the same script for groups instead of users as below, I am not getting any display

$adgroups = get-adgroup -searchbase "ou=test,dc=domain,dc=com" -filter * -Properties *

Foreach($adgroup in $adgroups)

{

if($adgroup.manager -ne $null)

{

```
$manager = Get-ADGroup -filter {Distinguishedname -eq $adgroup.manager}      

    if($($manager.enabled) -eq $false)      

    {
```

write-host "$($adgroup.SamAccountName),$($manager.SamAccountName)" -Path "C:\Users\test\Desktop\log.csv"

```
    }

}
```

}

Comment: $adusers = get-aduser -searchbase "ou=test,dc=domain,dc=com" -filter *|select samaccountname

foreach ( $aduser in $adusers )

{

$managers = (get-aduser (get-aduser $aduser -Properties manager).manager).samaccountName

foreach ( $manager in $managers)

{

$disabledmanager = Get-ADUser $($manager.name) -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} |Select samaccountname -ExpandProperty samaccountname

Add-Content "C:\Users\test\Desktop\log.csv" $aduser,$disabledmanager

}

}

Comment: please edit your post to pretty print your code.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
$adusers = get-aduser -searchbase "ou=test,dc=domain,dc=com" -filter * -Properties manager

Foreach($aduser in $adusers)
{
    if($aduser.manager -ne $null)
    {
        $manager = Get-ADUser -filter {Distinguishedname -eq $aduser.manager}
        if($($manager.enabled) -eq $false)
        {
            Add-Content -Value "$($aduser.SamAccountName),$($manager.SamAccountName)" -Path "C:\Users\test\Desktop\log.csv"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the subexpression in `if($($manager.enabled) -eq $false)`? Wouldn't `if( $manager.enabled -eq $false )` be enough?